# how to name a *.tif file with a specific date

Tags: python, date, filenames

I have to create some `*.tif` files and I need to name them with specific dates. For example, I have a `*.mat` file with a `152x380` matrix, each row corresponds to one `*.tif` file and a specific date (e.g. row 1 correspond to the first `*.tif` file and I need to name it as `20120101` (`YYYYMMDD`), the next row is the second `*.tif` file and its name has to be `20120102` and so on).
Do you guys know how to name the `*.tif` files according the explanation? You can see my code bellow

```
# Load *.mat file with the precipitation data
root_mat = r"f:\myfile\Precip10km.mat"
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(root_mat)
precipitation = mat['out'] #out variable contains the required data
precipitation = np.array(precipitation)

for i in range(len(precipitation)):
    array = precipitation[i]
    array = np.reshape(array, (19,20))
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    # In this line the variable "output_raster_name" need to assign a specific date
    # (e.g. the first file should be named 20120101, the second 20120102, the third 200120103
    # and so on)
    new_tiff = driver.Create(output_raster_name, array.shape[1],
                                     array.shape[0], 1, gdal.GDT_Int16)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `datetime.date` object and add days.

```py
startdate = datetime.date(2022, 7, 29)
for offset, datarow in enumerate(precipitation):
    rowdate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=offset)
    filename = rowdate.strftime("%Y%m%d.tif")
    output_raster_name = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    new_tiff = driver.Create(output_raster_name, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it something like:

```
        from datetime import datetime

        current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
        file_name = '$your-file-name' + '_' + current_time
        file_format = '$your-file-format'
        
        final_file_name_with_extension = file_name + '.' + file_format
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have some questions about it. First, in your third line `file_name = '$your-file-name' + '_' + current_time` you are just concatenating both `str` right? My question if it is possible to add one day to a specific date? e.g. `current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') +1` or something like that